# Having trouble with a very simple PHP array issue

Tags: php, arrays

All I need to two is remove the final two elements from an array, which only contains 3 elements, output those two removed elements and then output the non-removed element.  I'm having trouble removing the two elements, as well as keeping their keys.

My code is here http://pastebin.com/baV4fMxs

It is currently outputting : Java
Perl
Array

I want it to output:
[One] => Perl and [Two] => Java
[Zero] => PHP

Comment: [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: would help if you showed us your code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nEpMRLKk  there's my new code.  It works, except is there a way for it to display the array without the "Array" in the front of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to retrieve those two values being removed before getting rid of them. With this in mind, I suggest the use of `array_pop()` which simultaneously returns the last item in the array and removes it from the array.

```
$val = array_pop($my_array);
echo $val; // Last value
$val = array_pop($my_array);
echo $val; // Middle value
// Now, $my_array has only the first value
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to remove them both at the same time, while simultaneously storing them?

Comment: If you want them as an array, `$removed = array_splice($my_array, -2);` will return the last 2 elements as an array.

Comment: for example, here is my code: http://pastebin.com/baV4fMxs  It is outputting Java
Perl
Array  I want it to output [One] => Perl and [Two] => Java

Answer (score 2):

```
$last=array_splice($inputarray,-1);
//$last has now key=>value of last element

$middle=array_splice($inputarray,-1);
//$middle has now key=>value of middle element

//$inputarray has now only key=>value of first element
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that minded the last line of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned keys, so I assume it's an associative array. In order to remove an element, you can call the `unset` function, like this:

`unset ($my_array['my_key'])`

Do this for both elements that you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop) will do it for you quite easily:

```
$array = array( 'one', 'two', 'three');

$last = array_pop( $array); echo $last . "\n";
$second = array_pop( $array); echo $second . "\n";
echo $array[0];
```

**Output:**

```
three
two
one
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7Vyiiz)

Comment: @Downvoter, any comment? Especially since my answer is identical to the accepted answer?

Comment: Last sentence of the original question was "I'm having trouble removing the two elements, _as well as keeping their keys_."  `array_pop` does nothing to preserve/retrieve keys.  I think the accepted answer is incorrect as well.